# questions regarding react-native DatePickerIOS combined with modal

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app I'm trying to implement a `SegmentedControlIOS` that lets user choose from '5min from now', '15min from now', '30min from now', and 'custom time'.
So when the user choose from 'Xmin from now' the 'time' variable in `this.state` should be set X min from now, and if the user chooses 'custom time' then a modal with a timepicker and a confirm button should be shown and when the user chooses time and press the button `this.state.time` should be set to corresponding time.

The problem is:

1. I want to set `this.state.time` from `this.state.date` which is modified by the timepicker in the modal. But when I change time from timepicker, `this.state.date` is modified after I change the time in the picker once again. For example, if I change time from 11:05 to 11:10 and do `console.log(this.state.date)` then the console log shows 11:05.
2. And when I want to save the time by `this.setState` (time: this.state.date) it says undefined error evaluating (`this.state.date`).
3. Lastly, how can I set time to 5 minutes from now in react-native?

This is how far I got.

**Constructor and some functions**

```
export class RequestScene extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state={
      time: '',
      date: new Date(),
      timeZoneOffsetInHours: (-1) * (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
      modalVisible: false,
    };
  }

// function for SegmentedControlIOS (show timepicker when 'Custom' is chosen)
_onTimeChange = (event) => {
  if (event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
    this.setModalVisible(true);
  } else {
    // Q: how can I set time to '5 min from now' in react-native?
  }
}

// turn modal on and off
setModalVisible(visible) {
  this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}

// function for timepicker time change
onDateChange = (date) => {
  this.setState({date: date});
  console.log(this.state.date);
  // Q: this one works, but lags one move.
  // ie) if I change time from 11:05 to 11:10 from the picker, the console prints Wed Oct 05 2016 11:05:27 GMT+0800 (CST), then if I change time to 11:20 then the console prints 11:10, and so on.
}

// when the confirm button is pressed
confirmTime() {
  // Q: I want to save the date into this.state.time and close the modal.
  this.setState({time: this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()});
  this.setModalVisible(false);
  // But when the confirm button is pressed, simulator show red screen saying 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.date')
}
```

Below is the part of render function that shows the modal.
Everything works fine until the 'confirm time' button is pressed.
I'm not sure why this.state.date is printed in console but still shows undefined error when I'm trying to save it to this.state.time.

```
render() {
  return(
    // ...

    <View style={{height: 80, width: 360, padding: 10}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 14}}> Set Time: </Text>
            <SegmentedControlIOS
                values={['5min','15min','30min','custom']}
                selectedIndex={0}
                onChange={this._onTimeChange}
                tintColor='red'
            />
        </View>
        <View>
            <Modal
                animationType={"slide"}
                transparent={true}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
            >
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 300,
                        width: 360,
                        backgroundColor: 'white'
                    }}>
                        <DatePickerIOS
                            date = {this.state.date}
                            mode = "time"
                            minuteInterval={10}
                            onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
                            timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={this.state.timeZoneOffsetInHours * 60}
                        />

                        <Button
                            containerStyle = {{
                                backgroundColor: 'red',
                                width: 100,
                                height: 30,
                                padding: 5,
                                borderRadius: 3,
                            }}
                            style={{fontSize: 16, color: 'white'}}
                            onPress={this.confirmTime}
                        >
                            Confirm Time
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    // ...
  )
}
```